# Get Date of Birth and Town/City from Facebook SDK GraphUserCallback

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have facebook loggin set up within my app like below, the idea is to login and then do a `GraphUserCallback` so we can get the use information and then pass to my own register system so a user account can be set up for my app.

```
Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                            Response response) {

                        if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                        if (user != null) {
                            Map<String, Object> responseMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                            GraphObject graphObject = response
                                    .getGraphObject();
                            responseMap = graphObject.asMap();
                            Log.i("FbLogin", "Response Map KeySet - "
                                    + responseMap.keySet());

                            Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
                            String email = null;
                            String token = null;
                            String username = null;
                            String gender = null;
                            String birthday = null;
                            if (responseMap.get("email") != null) {
                                email = responseMap.get("email").toString();
                                username = responseMap.get("first_name").toString()+" "+responseMap.get("last_name").toString();
                                gender = responseMap.get("gender").toString();
                                token = session.getAccessToken();
                                /*birthday = responseMap.get("user_birthday").toString();

                                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, birthday, duration);
                                toast.show();*/

                                Intent i = new Intent(LogIn.this, FbLogin2Activity.class);
                                i.putExtra("Email", email);
                                i.putExtra("Token", token);
                                i.putExtra("Username", username);
                                i.putExtra("Gender", gender);
                                startActivity(i);
                            } else {
                                // Clear all session info & ask user to
                                // login again
                                if (session != null) {
                                    session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

When the user click a 'login' button:

```
fblogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
                if (session == null) {
                    Session.openActiveSession(LogIn.this, true,
                            statusCallback);
                } else if (!session.isOpened()) {
                    session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(
                            LogIn.this).setCallback(statusCallback)
                            .setPermissions(permissions)
                            );
                }
                /*Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FbLoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);*/
            }
        });
```

and my permissions are:

```
/***** FB Permissions *****/
permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
permissions.add("email");
permissions.add("user_birthday");
permissions.add("user_location");
/***** End FB Permissions *****/
```

The users email is returned and works however neither the users email or location is in the graphusecallback response.

Not sure if I have posted all that is needed so let me know but I cant work out why its not returning everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user's birthday will be in the `birthday` field, and the user's location will be in the `location` field (as opposed to `user_birthday` or `user_location`). So

```
birthday = responseMap.get("birthday").toString();
location = responseMap.get("location").get("name").toString();
```

should work.

Comment: `birthday = responseMap.get("birthday").toString();` works fine however `location = responseMap.get("location").get("name").toString();`gives The method get(String) is undefined for the type Object

Comment: Off the top of my head not sure how to get at location then, but via https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ (the location field) it's an object containing name and id.

Comment: Indeed and if you just do `responseMap.get("location").toString();` it returns work looks like a JSON with ID and name but it seems to think that `responseMap.get("location")` just returns a string?

Comment: Thanks for your help will bring this issue up in a new question